# Passing Node ID/Title to Next Page Webform Field

Tags: theming, webforms

I am new to drupal 8 and assisting my development team with design part. We are stuck in one place and not manage to move forward. We want to pass the node ID info to a webform filed which exist in another page. In the attached image I have explained what we want to achieve in **Drupal 8 Environment**, previously with PHP hack it was possible in drupal 7 but no idea how to achieve the same in drupal 8.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want: The user will create a node. Upon submission a form will be displayed showing the node id pre-filled in a form.
Make a module called example:

```
// example.module:
// we created a node type "product" (using UI). Saving this content
// will trigger the product form
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert().
 * @param \Drupal\node\NodeInterface
 */
function example_node_insert(NodeInterface $node) {
  if ($node->bundle() == 'product') {
    $nid = $node->id();
    $response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse(\Drupal\Core\Url::
    fromRoute('product.form', ['nid' => $nid])->toString());
    $response->send(); // When OO we will return the response object instead
  }
}

// example.routing.yml
product.form:
  path: '/form/product/{nid}'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\example\Form\ProductForm'
    _title: 'Product Form'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'

// src/Form/ProductForm
<?php

namespace Drupal\example\Form;


use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;

class ProductForm extends FormBase {

  /**
   * @var NodeInterface
   */
  protected $node;

  public function getFormId() {
    return 'example_product_form';
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $nid = null) {
    // if you need to load the node
    // $this->node = NodeInterface::load($nid);

    $form['node_id'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => 'Node ID',
      '#value' => $nid,
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // TODO: Implement submitForm() method.
    // you can redirect back to the node
  }

}
```

When dealing with this issue please realize the node id is not available until you save the node.

Answer (score 0):

Webform 8.x-5.x allows elements to be populated using query string parameters but you must enable this feature.

[image]

Another approach would be to set the element's default value to a `[current-page:query:?]` token like `[current-page:query:nid]`

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your comments. Actually my form is located in different URL; I need to catch current page title and pass this to my webform which is located in different URL. With your method it is getting the title of my webform page; I want my product page title to be passed in my webform.

Comment: In short, I want to populate my referral page title in my current webform input box.

Answer (score 0):

Trying using the [webform_submission:node:title] within the confirmation redirect URL's querystring parameter.

[image]

BTW, you must use an absolute URL. I just found this bug and created a issue on D.O. https://www.drupal.org/node/2864996